# Java - Make an object collection friendly

Tags: java, collections, hash, set, comparable

If an object holds a unique primary key, what interfaces does it need to implement in order to be collection friendly especially in terms of being efficiently sortable, hashable, etc...?

If the primary key is a string, how are these interfaces best implemented?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You must override `Object.equals()` and `Object.hashCode()`, and also implement the `Comparable` interface.  This will make your class fully "compliant" when doing any kind of sorting or hashing including using `Collections.sort(`), any `Map` class, or any `Set` class.  If there's even a *tiny* chance that the class will be put in some sort of collection, then it should *definitely* implement all three of these methods.

```
public class A implements Comparable<A>{
    private String key;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (!(obj instanceof A)) return false;

        A that = (A)obj;
        return this.key.equals(that.key);    
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        return key.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(A that){
        //returns -1 if "this" object is less than "that" object
        //returns 0 if they are equal
        //returns 1 if "this" object is greater than "that" object
        return this.key.compareTo(that.key);
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that if two objects are equal, then:

1. their hash codes must also be equal and
2. `compareTo()` must return 0.

Answer (score 12):

You must implement [equals](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29), [hashCode](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29), and (after implementing the [Comparable](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface) [compareTo](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29).

In each case, since you have a string which is a primary key, you may consider simply dispatching these calls to your string.  For example:

```
public class Friendly implements Comparable<Friendly>
{
    // presumably you've got other fields as well
    private String primaryKey;
    public Friendly(String primaryKey)
    {
        this.primaryKey = primaryKey;
    }

    public int compareTo(Friendly other)
    {
        return primaryKey.compareTo(other.primaryKey);
    }

    public int hashCode()
    {
        return primaryKey.hashCode();
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        return (o instanceof Friendly) && primaryKey.equals(((Friendly)o).primaryKey);
    }
}
```

Comment: And make sure that compareTo conforms to the "equals" contract.

Answer (score 5):

Strings are already very well suited for hashing and comparison, so if your objects can truly be uniquely identified by strings then you are in good shape.  Just make sure to implement the `Comparable` interface for sorting and override `equals` and `hashCode` (delegating to the primary key string) for hashing and you're good to go.

Answer (score 3):

If the primary key is an `Object` you need to decide if the sort order is based on the `Object` or the `Object`'s Primary Key `Object`.

In either case, the item to be sorted should implement the `Comparable` interface, with a proper `compareTo()` method.  Odds are excellent that means you'll have to override `equals()` and `hashCode()` too, as only some of the primary key Objects are likely to have proper default implementations.

If you want to sort based on some non-natural sort order, then also implement a few "extra" `Comparators`.  Ordered `Collections` support alternative `Comparators`.